# Perl CGI::Session MySQL thaw utf-8 data

Tags: mysql, perl, session, utf-8

I'm using CGI::Session to store utf-8 session data into a MySQL DB with YAML as serializer, which works fine. The problem is that on thaw, the session data doesn't seem to get decoded into Perls internal format, although the database handle passed to the session constructor is configured to do so.
Applying decode_utf8 manually on each session parameter right after thawing does fix this, but that's rather inconvenient.

Here's my setup:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

$dbh->{'mysql_enable_utf8'} = 1;
$dbh->do('set names utf8');

$session = CGI::Session->new("driver:MySQL;serializer:yaml", undef, {
  TableName   => "session",
  IdColName   => "id",
  DataColName => "data",
  Handle      => $dbh,
} ) or die CGI::Session->errstr;

# column 'data' of table 'session' is of type mediumtext, has charset utf8 and collation utf8_unicode_ci
```

Example snippet:

```
binmode(STDIN, ":encoding(utf8)");
binmode(STDOUT, ":encoding(utf8)");

if( !defined $session->param('first_name') ){
  $session->param('first_name','jörg');
}

print $session->param('first_name');
```

On first run this would output: 'jörg'

On second run (with the name now coming from the session table): 'jÃ¶rg'

As mentioned above, this would fix it:

```
binmode(STDIN, ":encoding(utf8)");
binmode(STDOUT, ":encoding(utf8)");

if( !defined $session->param('first_name') ){
  $session->param('first_name','jörg');
} else {
  $session->param('first_name',decode_utf8($session->param('first_name')));
}

print $session->param('first_name');
```

(I do store 'first_name' in a 'person' table using the exact same database handle and read/write/output from there works flawlessly.)

So, why isn't the data decoded properly into Perls format via CGI::Session, or how can I tell CGI::Session to do so?
This behavior also results in serializers Dumper, Storable, and FreezeThaw to crash when trying to thaw data which has been corrupted before. 
E.g. Dumper just cuts the session data at the 'ö' of 'jörg' when it's not in Perls internal format.

Thank you very much for any hints on this and please forgive misnomers on my part. I'm just trying to get my head around the unicode-in-perl issue.
(Yes, I already read many of the general guides and how-to's but sadly couldn't find anything on the session-mysql subject.)

Best regards,
Thomas

*Updated according to simbaque (thanks for the hint), but it's indeed not the issue here.*

Comment: Your code looks a bit old-style with the example `new CGI::Session`. You should add `use strict` and `use warnings` although I don't think that is the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

In your samples, I see that you're setting your output to UTF8, but do you ever set your input to UTF8?  `CGI::Session` [has a warning](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Session#A-Warning-about-UTF8) about UTF8, and in that section it talks about setting both your input and output to UTF8.  What happens in your program if you include `binmode STDIN, ":encoding(utf8)";`?

Comment: I actually do set `binmode STDIN, ":encoding(utf8)";` already, sorry I didn't add it to the snippet, updated it now. But that doesn't seem to be it cause the session params are init via the database handle and not via STDIN, right?

Comment: Taking a closer look at CGI::Session, I don't know that CGI::Session::Serialize::yaml supports UTF8.  The last version of CGI::Session that released with YAML support was 4.10, and that was in March '06.  Is there any reason why you have to use YAML?  Would upgrading CGI::Session and try freezethaw or storable be a viable option?

Comment: The data column was preferred to be human readable, hence the choice for YAML or the default serializer Data::Dumper.
Your hint about the former possibly being outdated made me take a look at Dumper again. The problem is of similar nature here. utf8 characters get escaped by dumper and are restored on thaw almost correctly but without perls utf8 flag. Which makes dumper corrupt (cutof) the session data on the respective unicode character.
Found a workaround for this, also using storable as you suggested, posted as answer since it might help others but it doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the table column was not declared `CHARACTER SET utf8`.

Comment: Sadly, that's not it. The data column is declared with `CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci`.

Comment: Let's do some debugging...  From Perl, dump the hex of `jörg` at every step.  `jörg` correctly encoded as utf8 is hex `6AC3B67267`; `jörg` encoded as latin1 is hex `6AF67267`; "double-encoded": `6AC383C2B67267`.  I don't know the details of getting hex in Perl, but it probably involves `unpack('H*', $text)`.  [More latin1 & utf8 encodings](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#8_bit_encodings)

Comment: Ok, here is what I got:

Setting the variable in perl: 'jörg'  `6A F6 72 67`

After thawing from the session table: 'jÃ¶rg' `6A C3 B6 72 67`

While in the DB (in session->data column as well as person->first_name column) the utf8 encoding stays unchanged: `6A C3 B6 72 67`

It seems that the name gets encoded to utf8 correctly on write to session table, doesn't get decoded on read when thawing, but for some reason also doesn't get double encoded on the next write to the session table, which stumps me.

Comment: The "right" thing to do is to go 100% utf8.  That would involve figuring out how to get the original string in utf8.  Where did it come from?  The "second choice" is to figure out how (or why) Yaml is converting.  I'm afraid I don't have any clues of either.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't answer original question exactly but these 2 options might be valid workarounds for others having similar problems:

1. Using default serializer Data::Dumper and forcing it to use pure perl version seems to be able to restore the data as desired with utf8 flag being set. Downside is that it's supposed to be significantly slower than the perl/XS version which is used by default.

   `$Data::Dumper::Useperl = 1;`
2. Using serializer storable and changing the data column to be of type `mediumblob`. This probably bypasses the whole encoding issue altogether since you're reading and writing just binary data from the DB. But data column is not human readable anymore.